# Is there a way we can calculate estimated model training time when applying machine learning with scikitlearn or otherwise?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Many a times specially when the dataset is large or has multiple features, it takes ages (long hours) for sci-kit learn to train the model. Since it is using the computational resources, working on other things during this time on the same machine becomes exceptionally slow, thus, reducing overall productivity.

Is there  a way to estimate the time required for training a model? It doesnt have to be actually beforehand but it can be estimated once the training has started.

I have tried scitime but thats a very invasive method. Would prefer a method that is more tightly coupled with sklearn functionality.

Comment: Interesting question. If it's about estimating after training has started, I assume you're looking for a way to measure remaining progress left? For iteration-based algorithms, it should be possible to wrap existing models in a custom class that allows accessing the internal iteration counter.

Comment: the training isnt a linear process, hence its not that straight forward to calculate remaining time based on iterations alone.